# Is it normal for syndaemon to use 100% CPU?

Tags: 11.04, synaptics

<s>Since I upgrade to 11.04, the new Ubuntu One daemon (syndaemon) is using 100% at somewhat random intervals. I'm not updating any files in the folder to my knowledge, so it's a bit confusing as to why it would do this.</s>

Is this normal behaviour? If it is, then I understand, (only, when it uses so much CPU, my system becomes almost unusable!) :)

EDIT:
OOPS! It wasn't actually Ubuntu-one (I had problems with it in the past and got the process name mixed up in my head/memory). Chipaca's answer is accurate for me.

Comment: I've also had Ubuntu One's sync daemon go nuts in the past, so I can easily see the confusion.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: \o/ glad I'm not alone :P (I honestly felt a bit silly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syndaemon is «a program that monitors keyboard activity and disables the touchpad when the keyboard is being used». Nothing related to Ubuntu One. The fix to this particular issue seems to have been released already; if you're experiencing this behavior with an up-to-date Natty, please mention this on [that bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/754470).

Comment: Thanks Chipaca! My apologies for getting the process names mixed up :P (for some reason - silly me)!!!